# How to call web api in angular service

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api

I am new to angular. Can some one help me to know how to call my api in angular code ?

My We API is -

```
[HttpGet,Route("api/customer/getCustomer/{name}")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> getCustomer([FromUri] string name) {
...}
```

And in anular I am tring to call like below -

customer.component.ts -

```
name = "test";
getCustomer(){
this.custService.getCustomer(this.name).subscribe((data) => {
this.cust = JSON.parse(data.toString());
});
}
```

custService code -

```
getCustomer(name){
 return this.http.get('https://localhost:44400/api/customer/getCustomer/', +name)
}
```

Comment: The comma inside the `get` call needs to be removed: `this.http.get('https://localhost:44400/api/customer/getCustomer/' + name)`. Also if the back-end is already sending an object in valid JSON, the `JSON.parse` and `toString` isn't required. You could directly do `this.cust = data`.

Answer (score 0):

customer.component.ts

```
export class CustomerComponent implements OnInit {
name: string;
cust: any;
constructor(private custService: CustService){
}
ngOnInit(){
    this.name = "test";
    this.getCustomer();
}

getCustomer(){
    this.custService.getCustomer(this.name).subscribe((data) => {
    this.cust = data;
    },error => {
        console.log(error);
    }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best implementation is :

1. Define a config file for your server-side URL :

> ```
>   const  serviceBaseUrl: 'https://localhost:44400/api',
>
>
>
>  public getCustomer(name:string): Observable<Customer> {
>     return this.httpClient.get<any>(`${serviceBaseUrl}/customer/getCustomer/`+name);
>   }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

First import HttpClientModule in app.module.ts file and set on imports:

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

imports: [
BrowserModule,
HttpClientModule,
],
```

Now create a service and add this code on your service file

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

export class EmployeeService {
private url='Enter your api url';
constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }
getPost(){
 return this.httpClient.get(this.url);
 }
}
```

Now in app.component.ts file add this code

```
import {ApiService} from './services/api.service';

export class AppComponent {
posts:any;
constructor(private post:EmployeeService) {}

ngOnInit(){
this.post.getPost().subscribe(response =>{
this.posts=response;
console.log(this.posts);
 })
}
}
```

Now in app.component.html file

```
 <tr *ngFor="let post of posts">
<td>{{post.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

Now done, Save and Run your application

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Injectable, model } from '@angular/core';
import { AddCategoryRequest } from '../models/add-category-request.model';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CategoryService {

  constructor(private http : HttpClient) { }
  
  addCategory(model: AddCategoryRequest): Observable<void> {
    return this.http.post<void>("https://localhost:7217/api/categories", model, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
    });
  }
  

}



import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AddCategoryRequest } from '../models/add-category-request.model';
import { CategoryService } from '../services/category.service';
import { response } from 'express';
import { error } from 'console';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-category',
  templateUrl: './add-category.component.html',
  styleUrl: './add-category.component.css'
})
export class AddCategoryComponent {

  model : AddCategoryRequest;

  constructor(private categoryService : CategoryService){
    this.model = {
      Name: '',
      UrlHandle: '',
    };
  }

  onFormSubit() {

    this.categoryService.addCategory(this.model).subscribe({
      next : (response) => {
        
      }, 
      error : (error) => {

      }
    });

  }

}
```

model

```
export interface AddCategoryRequest {
    Name: string;
    UrlHandle: string;
}
```